# Winhttp Does Not Post File

Tags: php, c++, winhttp

I have combed all over here for similar questions and have done all suggestions but for some weird reason my code doesn't upload the file to the server.

C++ Code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Winhttp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")


PCHAR sendWebRequest(LPWSTR szServerNameOrIP, LPWSTR szVerb, LPWSTR szServerPath, PCHAR szFileToPost)
{
 HINTERNET hSession;
 HINTERNET hConnect;
 HINTERNET hRequest;

 BOOL bResults = FALSE;

 LPCWSTR szUserAgent = L"MyCustomUserAgent";

 DWORD dwSize, dwDownloaded;
 PCHAR szTempRespBuff;
 PCHAR szRawResponse = (PCHAR)malloc(MAX_PATH); 

 strcpy_s(szRawResponse, MAX_PATH, "");

 int nBuffSize;

try{

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(szUserAgent, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    if (hSession == NULL)
    {
        //printf("[x] Could not create session!\n");
        MessageBox(0, L"WinOpenError", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, szServerNameOrIP, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);
    if (hConnect == NULL)
    {
        //printf("[x] Could not connect to the host!\n");
        MessageBox(0, L"WinConnectError", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, szVerb, szServerPath, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH);
    if (hRequest == NULL)
    {
        //printf("[x] Failed to get request handle!\n");
        MessageBox(0, L"WinOpenRequestError", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    // Add request headers.
    bResults = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, 
                                        L"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaUZw4AF9WYYzUrpM",
                                        -1L, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);

    if (!bResults)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"WinHttpAddRequestHeadersError", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    CHAR szPostData0[440],
         szPostData1[60],
         szPostTemp[120];

    ZeroMemory(szPostData0, sizeof(szPostData0));
    ZeroMemory(szPostData1, sizeof(szPostData1));
    ZeroMemory(szPostTemp, sizeof(szPostTemp));


    strcpy_s(szPostData0, 440, "------WebKitFormBoundaryaUZw4AF9WYYzUrpM\r\n");

    PCHAR fileName  = PathFindFileNameA(szFileToPost);
    wsprintfA(szPostTemp, "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", fileName);
    strcat_s(szPostData0, 440, szPostTemp);

    strcat_s(szPostData0, 440, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");

    strcpy_s(szPostData1, 60, "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarygQFYVyK9cnuuaQYb--\r\n");

     // Open the existing file.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(szFileToPost, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL,
                         OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"CreateFileAError", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    //Make sure size is not more than 300kb
    size_t fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (fileSize > 307200)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"FileSize too large!", L"", 0);
        throw(0);
    }


    //Send Request
    int lenBytes = strlen(szPostData0 + 1) + strlen(szPostData1 + 1) + fileSize;

    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS , 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, lenBytes, NULL);
    if (!bResults)
    {
        //printf("[x] Failed to send request!\n");
        int error = GetLastError();

        TCHAR szbuff[25];
        wsprintf(szbuff, L"Error %d", error);
        MessageBox(0, L"WinSendRequestError", szbuff, 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    //Write First Post Data
    DWORD numberOfBytesRead, numberOfBytesWritten;
    WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, szPostData0, (DWORD)strlen(szPostData0+1), &numberOfBytesWritten);

    //Write File Buffer
    PCHAR fileBytes = (PCHAR)malloc(fileSize);
    ReadFile(hFile, fileBytes, fileSize, &numberOfBytesRead, NULL);
    WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, fileBytes, fileSize, &numberOfBytesWritten);

    
    //Write Last Post Data
    WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, szPostData1, (DWORD)strlen(szPostData1+1), &numberOfBytesWritten);


    //Receive the response
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
    if (!bResults)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
            wsprintfA(szPostTemp, "WinHttpReceiveResponseError %d", err);

            MessageBoxA(0, szPostTemp, "", 0);
        throw(0);
    }

    //Read Response Received

    do {

        // Check for available data.
        dwSize = 0;
        if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize) )
        {
            //printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError() );
            MessageBox(0, L"WinHttpQueryDataAvailableError", L"", 0);
            throw(0);
        }

        // Allocate space for the buffer.
        nBuffSize = (dwSize+1);
        szTempRespBuff = (PCHAR)malloc(nBuffSize);

        if (szTempRespBuff == NULL)
        {
            //printf( "Error allocation space for response");
            throw(0);
        }

        // Read the data.
        ZeroMemory(szTempRespBuff, nBuffSize);

        if(WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)szTempRespBuff, dwSize, &dwDownloaded ))
            strcat_s(szRawResponse, MAX_PATH, szTempRespBuff);

        // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
        free(szTempRespBuff);

    }while (dwSize > 0);


    //Close Handles
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);

    return szRawResponse;

}catch(...)
{
    if(hSession)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    if(hConnect)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);

    if(hRequest)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
}


  return "WINHTTP_ERROR";

}

  int main()
{
    PCHAR response = sendWebRequest(L"127.0.0.1", L"POST", L"/panel/ups.php", "hello.txt");

    MessageBoxA(0, response, "", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
      $file_ext = explode('.',$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
      $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_ext));
      
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png", "txt");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file or Txt";
      }
      
      if($file_size > 1048576){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 1 MB';
      }
      
      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>
      
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the "success" echo on server (php) but no file is uploaded into the images directory. I found out that the file has no `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']` is 0 bytes.

Comment: A good place to start would be to use wireshark to verify whether your c++ code is not sending the right data or whether your php script isn't processing it correctly

Comment: For a start, I would suggest you try to reproduce this using `curl` as HTTP client, eliminating that part of the code. If that works, you already know the problem is not in the C++ part. Concerning the code snippets here, please make sure they qualify as [mcve] and that they are formatted consistently. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @AlanBirtles i used wireshark like you suggested. Uploading file with a browser and c++ code have the same payload. When i do it with a browser, hello.txt is seen on the server side but not when i try same with c++. I don't know how to show a wireshark log of both browser and c++ file upload :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am taking the tour. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. When I use a shorter boundary , the file gets uploaded . When I use a longer it doesn’t . On the server side I listened for file error which returned 3 (partial file uploaded). I don’t know why this is so but I guess I’d have to stick to a shorter name .